# Open a pop-up window with external page while clicking image from a page in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, popupwindow

I have situation to open a popup window to a external php file which is placed in wordpress theme folder while clicking a page link or image.
I pass the page ID & Permalink from the page where did I click to that external php file ?
Please help me..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try this..it might help you..

download the thickbox js file and keep this code in the script

```
$("#id of the image or any button").click(function(){
     var url = "Give the url of the page that you wanna open in the popup";
     tb_show('<h3></h3>', url+'?KeepThis=true&TB_iframe=true&height=150&width=500');
});
```

make sure that you have the thickbox file included into the file from where you have kept the above script